# How to make button in ComboBox do something on click

Tags: java, kotlin, user-interface, javafx, desktop

```
    val bar = VBox()
    val list: ObservableList<Button> = FXCollections.observableArrayList()

    val button = Button("20")

    button.setOnAction {
        changeFont(textWindow, button.text.toInt())
        println("works")
    }

    list.add(button)

    val comboBox: ComboBox<*> = ComboBox<Button>(list)
```

the changeFont is what I would want to happen, but the print statement wont work either.

Comment: don't use nodes as items - instead use (f.i.) strings and a custom cell

Comment: Ill try and try using custom cells. im not sure exactly how that will help me, just confused.

Comment: nevermind. im just stupid. using strings was the answer, sorry for doubting you good sir.

Comment: can u put that for an answer? Or should i just delete this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this issue,

```
val bar = VBox()
val list: ObservableList<Int> = FXCollections.observableArrayList(1,2,3)
val comboBox: ComboBox<*> = ComboBox<Int>(list)

comboBox.setOnAction {
    changeFont(textWindow, comboBox.value())
    println("works")
}
```

this worked for me, thanks to @kleopatra for answering in the comments.